# Android Camera how to show buttons during full screen preview

Tags: android, camera

I am working on a Android camera apps with target level 2.1
however I find difficult while I enter the full screen mode,
I want to show button during the preview, but it actually hidden, so any one know how to do with it??

this is the code find on this website and have a litte bit modify
http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/39.html

```
    Preview preview;
    Button buttonClick;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.cameralayout);

        preview = new Preview(this);
        ((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.preview)).addView(preview);

        setContentView(R.layout.cameralayout);

        buttonClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonClick);
        buttonClick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                preview.camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
            }
        });
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate'd");
    }
```

this is the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/preview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonClick"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
                android:text="Click" />
</FrameLayout>
```

and the manifest has set the theme to make it in full screen

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

So how to make my button visible with the present of full screen preview
Thank you very much~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are missing the `SurfaceView` view. 
Inside `FrameLayout` layout put the `SurfaceView` which will hold the camera preview, and your button below.

Comment: sorry, I tried but return exception that can't even turn on the camera...
could you please kindly show me the part the code...
I can't figure out the solution...

Answer (score 0):

after line `buttonClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonClick);`
add these lines

```
((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.preview)).removeView(buttonClick);
((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.preview)).addView(buttonClick);
```

now you can see your button....

happy learning.. :)